# convert a string into list but separate single quote and apostrophe without using re

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large text file with text written in the forms of paragraphs.
I need to convert the string into a list, but single quotes and apostrophes need to be treated differently.

For example:

```
a = "He said 'Hello. Don't sleep.'"
```

What I want the output to be:

```
lst = ['"','He','said',"'","Hello",'.',"Don't","sleep",".","'".'"']
```

Single quotes are their own element, but apostrophes should remain with the word.

Comment: I think using .split()

Comment: I tried once, but if using .split(), the 'Hello. will not separate into ["'",'Hello,'.']

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
a = "He said 'Hello. Don't sleep.'"
a.split(' ')
#['He', 'said', "'Hello.", "Don't", "sleep.'"]
```

Comment: I tried once, but if using .split(), the 'Hello. will not separate into ["'",'Hello,'.']